# appending elements to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a list element dynamically to already existing list.

I've a list in the form,

```
<ul id="test">
    <li class="testField">YYAAHOOOOOO<li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to add an extra item to this list using jQuery append or after...

What I did was:

```
$(".testField").after("<li class='testField'>TEST MESSENGER</li>");
```

Used after function as append did not work, the after function works fine first time as there is only one element with the class name `testField`, but as the list grows, the after function will add the list items to all elements present,

To make it clear, on first trial I will get an output:

```
<ul id="test">
    <li class="testField">YYAAHOOOOOO<li>
    <li class='testField'>TEST MESSENGER</li>
</ul>
```

If I try the to add another element now for example `<li class='testField'>GOOGLE</li>`, the output will be like:

```
<ul id="test">
    <li class="testField">YYAAHOOOOOO<li>
    <li class='testField'>GOOGLE</li>
    <li class='testField'>TEST MESSENGER</li>
    <li class='testField'>GOOGLE</li>
</ul>
```

I thought about using ids, but I am trying to have an option to remove elements from the list too... So if I try to append to an undefined id, it will return error. Is there anyway to find the first element inside a list and append the element to that first one?

Comment: When asking questions, it's best to include the most relevant information early on. In the question above, you've pretty thoroughly buried a very important piece of information: *"is there anyway to find the first element inside a list and append the element to that first one??"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".testField:first").after("<li class='testField'>TEST MESSENGER</li>");
```

this will make sure that you are appending after the first element only

Comment: +1 for seeing the detail buried at the bottom of the question. (Well, that and answering it correctly as well!)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do this without jQuery:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');                       // Create a List item.
    li.setAttribute("class", "testfield");                   // Set the li's class
    li.addChild(document.createTextNode("Your Text Here!")); // Set the li's text
document.getElementById("test").addChild(li);                // Append the li to the list
```

It's slightly more code, yes, but it's pretty much what jQuery does under the hood. (And faster, too)

If you want to add the new ul after the first `li` already in the list, replace the last line with:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("test");
if(ul.children.length > 1){              // If the list has 2 or more children (li's)
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.children[1]); // Insert the new item before the second item in the list.
}else{
    document.getElementById("test").addChild(li); 
}
```

Now, why am I posting a answer that requires more code?
Anything that can be done in jQuery can be done in native JS. I think it's good to have multiple different answers available on SO, especially if they use different techniques to do the same thing. That way, users can chose for themselves: short'n easy (jQuery), or if they don't want to use the library, native code.